# SFMC user not added to All Subscriber List

Tags: marketing-cloud, list, subscriber

my expecttaion was once i sended an email to a new subscriber he gets automatically added to the all Subscriber list. Emails are received.

I now sended emails to new subscriber with Subscriber KEy 110-111 but when i search in All Subscriber i cant find this subscriber.

When i want to create this user with his private Key System tells me i cant save because the subscriber with  Subscriber Key "110-111" is already used.

When its used why cant i find it in All subscriber list?

Hope anybody can give me a hint on that. @Data_Kid :)

[image: DE incl subscriber key setup]

[image: Subscriber Key not available when searching for it]

Comment: You have to use the all subscribers list as the publication list and select the option to add to all subscribers if it’s a triggered send

Comment: i used the all subscriber as publication list :(

Comment: The MDMId field on your Data Extension is a number data type, which wouldn't accept a dash (110-111) - I'd confirm the MDMId value and see if that's in All Subscribers

Comment: Maybe the same issue? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222855/marketing-cloud-subscriber-import-marking-records-failed-due-to-false-dupes

Answer (score 1):

If you send it in a normal send via a dataextension, make sure which field you relate to your subscriber key in the properties tab of the dataextension. If its not your subscriberkey but instead a different field like email this record will be created with a subscriberkey of that email value.

Email Studio -> All Subscribers -> Search where Subscriber Key -> is Equal to 110-111. Look for Subscribers in All Subscribers. -> Find Now

Comment: Hi, i have SUBSCRIBER RELATIONSHIP: ID_1 relates to Subscribers on Subscriber Key. But if i send email from DE to these subscriber the subscriber itself is still not added to All Subscriber list.

Comment: I added 2 screenshots maybe it makes thinkgs more clear @Johannes_Schapdick

Comment: Have you recently deleted that subscriber via contact builder with a Contact Deletion Settings which makes this subscriber go into supression status? When this subscriber is under RestrictedContactStatus it won't show and you cannot add him until the moment the deletion is complete

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are describing seem specific to the one that happens after a contact has been deleted using the Contact Delete process.

If you recently deleted some contacts, they are now in the Suppression period - the default length is 14 days, but it's possible that you used a different period.

In that timeframe, contacts won't be visible in the UI, but they will be stored in the backend, to prevent importing them by mistake once again into the account (and in your case, to prevent re-adding them to All Subscribers list).

After the Suppression period passes, they will be deleted permanently. Only then you will be able to re-add them.

Here is the documentation:

Contact Deletion in Contact Builder: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5
Contacts Analytics in Contact Builder: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_analytics.htm&type=5