# Marketing Cloud Subscriber Import marking records failed due to false dupes?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to import Subscribers into my Master Subscriber List using Automation Studio, upon running the automation I get an email sent stating the rows failed to insert and under reason it says the following:

```
ValidationErrors:
    Duplicate: 100
```

All of the records are definitely not in the Subscriber table either via the Subscriber Key or the Email Address (my subscriber keys are not the same as the email address).

Any ideas why this may be? I am working from the Parent Business Unit.

Comment: Maybe two persons face the same error: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222823/sfmc-user-not-added-to-all-subscriber-list

Comment: This looks like a similar issue, I'm doing the import via an automation whereas that user is inserting via the UI but the issue appears to be the same.